# Curious about Squeeze theorem specifics

Tags: limits

I have just learned about the Squeeze theorem but noticed that it's never explicitly proved that if we have an open interval with $x\in(a,b)$ with $a<c<b$, then the limit $\lim(x\to c)g(x)$ always exists if we have $f(x)\leq g(x) \leq h(x)$. It seems that this fact is always either assumed or skipped entirely. Any ideas on how this would be proved?

Comment: $\lim_{x\to c}$ of what?

Comment: *Who* assumes that?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem#Proof) has two proofs.

Comment: It would be nice if you can include the proof you have trouble with.